# Jsoup: Selecting elements that have a single class

Tags: java, jsoup

I am parsing some tables from a website, and specifically I am trying to extract the following cells by class name:

```
<td class=" text_bold">example</td>
```

I use the standard Jsoup selector for extracting tags with a class, as follows:

```
Elements cells = doc.select("td.text_bold");
```

The problem is that there are other cells which are also selected because they have both the `text_bold` class and another class, for example:

```
<td class="text_bold text_align_left" valign="top" width="150">example</td>
```

Is there a simple way to filter only Elements that have a single class as specified in the `select()` method?

Comment: Try `doc.select("td[class='text_bold']")`.

Comment: @Vulcan Thanks for the suggestion. Seems like it should work with `[attribute=value]` but it returns 0 elements.

Comment: Is there a space before or after `text_bold` but still within the class declaration? If so, you may want to use `^=` for startsWith, `$=` for endsWith, or if the spaces are on either side and/or are inconsistent, use the regex selector `~=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fallen in this situation before. However, the trick i have used is that:

- first take all the element as `Elements` with target class: for your context `"text_bold"`
- Then traverse each element comparing their class name which can be got using `Element.className()` function. If class name is `"aClass bClass"` format this function will return it as one class name.

**For example:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<td class=\"text_bold text_align_left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"150\">example</td>
<td class=\" text_bold\">example</td>");
        Elements elms = doc.select("td.text_bold");
         for(Element e:elms)
             if(e.className().trim().equals("text_bold")) 
                             //^^^<--trim is required as, 
                            // their can be leading and trailing space 
             {
                 System.out.println(e.className());
                 // do my thing

             }
```